# Microsoft Dynamics AX 2012 R3 XDS Security on Finacial Dimesion

Tags: sql-server, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I'm trying to create an AX security framework for one of my client. The key task here is to enable **Branch Accounting** in AX 2012 R3 environment. Which means i'm required to filter different *transactions / customers / vendors / Transfer orders* on the basis of Location & Financial dimension BU respectively such as Each Branch (location) should see records of there respective branch.

I created my custom **security roles** enabled **XDS framework** on them, it was easy in the case of *customer, vendor* etc for which I had an Location wise field.

But in case of transactions i.e **'LedgerJournalTrans'** Table I am not able to filter on the basis of Financial dimension. As the field **LedgerDimesion** is a combination of different dimensions its hard to use it in a AOT query.

If any one give an insight on how to filter transactions or any other records on the basis of Financial dimension combinations  ?

*Note: I've already studied the white paper to filter through dimensions on XDS but the example mentioned there is based on the **myDepartment** table and methods which I cannot use in my scenario*

[Link to White Paper for reference](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh335188.aspx)

Comment: I can't help as I'm unfamiliar with this but it my be useful to others if you [edit] your question to include a link to that white paper. It also helps if you can show what you've already tried.

Comment: [Link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh335188.aspx)

_I'm trying to make a similar query that has been specified in the above linked white paper, but my query should filter FD on the criteria I provide not on the basis of 'myDepartment' Table_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a query or view to get values for each ledger dimension.
You can get this info by joining DimensionAttributeValueGroupCombination (this has ledger dimension id), DimensionAttributeLevelValue (field DisplayValue is the dimension value), DimensionAttributeValue (DimensionAttribute RecId). 
Now you can use this view or modify it to filter by dimenison values.

MyDepartments temp table has a method named XDS which is automatically called to fill the data. Refresh of this table can be per session or per invocation.
You can use this to make your own user based filter data.

Answer (score 0):

You can add some code in the init() method of your Query that you use in Your XDS policy.

the code should get the ledgerdimension  field and get the dimension value that you want to filter based on the user dimension mapping.